# Strip the end </div> if the start tag is broken regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Couldn't find a working solution in the past posts on stackoverflow. I need to strip the end `</div>` if the start tag is broken.

For instance strip `</div>` if:

`div id="something">Something</div>`

`div class="something">Something</div>`

`div>Something</div>`

PS I'd prefer not to use htmlPurifier or heavy functions. These are the only examples I need a solution for. Just a simple regex would do.

Comment: You don't need regex for this, you can just do a string search and if it doesn't contain '< div >' then fix it, but you'd be better using a library like htmlPurifier.

Comment: Those examples are pretty forward and can be done with string searches, but what if there are nested divs like `div>A div<div>Nested div</div></div>`? This is trickier!

Comment: @Coz do I really need to use htmlPurifier for stand along examples like those above? Seems like an overkill.

Comment: @HasseBjörk there will be no nested divs. I just need a simple regex for the examples above. Can't figure it out on my own for whatever reason.

Comment: Your sample strings are [easy to fix](https://regex101.com/r/lV4lL1/1). The question is too unclear as to what context they appear in, how complex the tag structure can be, and in general, when you have to fix HTML, the right answer is "at the provider's side".

Comment: If that's all you need you can use striptags($string) to remove the div (broken or not) then add them back on.

Comment: @stribizhev so what you're saying is it's easier to find unclosed start tags and just close them instead of stripping the end tags? That's cleaver. Maybe that's what I should do.

Comment: @stribizhev what does `<$&` exactly do (I mean $ and &)?

Comment: `$&` is a back-reference to the whole match. No need for capturing groups (that is, `(...)`) as the whole match is already Group 0.

Comment: A possible way is to use the automatic fixes of DOMDocument, however orphan `>` will be replaced with html entities. (but this can be a good thing)

Comment: @stribizhev And lastly how would you do the same in php?

Comment: @stribizhev What would be a back end reference in php?

Comment: No idea what you mean, maybe [this](http://ideone.com/w2d1zA). Have a look at Casimir's suggestion, by the way.

Comment: Sure enough it's `<\0`. Very cool. I will look at Casimir's suggestion too.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way is to use the automatic fixes provided by DOMDocument:

```
$html = <<<'LOD'
div id="something">Something</div>

div class="something">Something</div>

div>Something</div>
LOD;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<root>' . $html . '</root>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

echo substr($dom->saveHTML(), 6, -8);
```

result:

```html
div id="something"&gt;Something

div class="something"&gt;Something

div&gt;Something
```

orphan closing tags are automatically removed and orphans `>` are replaced with html entities.